# Refresh/recalculate css

Tags: css, webkit, height, refresh, web-inspector

```
<div id="box1">
    <div id="box2" style="height:60%"></div>
</div>
```

**Update** - It turned out to be something silly: there was a parent div that I hadn't closed properly. I'm still curious why changing some css in the web inspector managed to fix it. Thanks everyone!

---

The problem happens in webkit browsers (Safari, Mobile Safari, Chrome, Android browser), but doesn't in Firefox:

On window resize, box1's height is changed with javascript, but box2 doesn't expand/contract to be 60% of box1's new height UNTIL I go into web inspector and manually change any css rule of any element as long as it's not the style attribute of that element. (So the rule I change has to originate from inline css or a .css file - but it doesn't matter which file)

What is going on? Why does this happen? If there is some sort of recalculation or refreshing of the css, how do I force this to happen upon window resize?

Comment: Why not just resize the `div#box2` in your JS as well?

Comment: Tried it - still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be something silly: there was a parent div that I hadn't closed properly. I'm still curious why changing some css in the web inspector managed to fix it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a browser bug.

Maybe something like `elemnt_box2.stye=element_box2.style` would trigger an update, but this would be a workaround.

Bear in mind that DOM updates from Javascript are not fully-processed immediately, but after the script has finished executing. This is for efficiency. It might mean that cascading changes are not visible to the script until the next entry point.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where toggling `float:left` off then immediately back on would make a small `div` jump up or down a line, but like here, only on Chrome, not in Firefox.  The solution that worked for me was removed an extra `clear:left` somewhere.